# Can a .NET Core API be Called "Middleware"?

Tags: .net-core, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, semantics

This question is purely about semantical convention. I came onto a project where the architect named the API layer (.NET Core API) solution "middleware."

I have always referred to these projects as the API, e.g. `MyMagicCompanyAPI`.

To me, Middleware is usually the part of the code that intercepts http requests and does something before the request info is passed down the pipeline, e.g. [.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or the [Angular Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

On that note, is it wrong to call an API middleware? If not, is it preferable/more accurate to just call it an API over calling it middelware?

Comment: As you said, semantics. Or better yet, it is a matter of context. A whole API can be a middleware in a distributed system. .net core's use of the term for their architecture is not the only interpretation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a .NET Core API be Called “Middleware”?

Short answer: **YES**

Depending on the context in which it is being used.

.NET Core's, Angular's, *(et al.)* use of the term within their architecture is not the only contextual use of the term *middleware*.

As you said, semantics. Or better yet, it is a matter of context.

A whole API can be a middleware in a distributed system.

> ### In distributed applications
>
> The term is most commonly used for software that enables communication and management of data in distributed applications.
>
> ### Other examples
>
> The term middleware is used in other contexts as well. Middleware is sometimes used in a similar sense to a software driver, an abstraction layer that hides detail about hardware devices or other software from an application.

Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware

> On that note, is it wrong to call an API middleware? If not, is it preferable/more accurate to just call it an API over calling it middelware?

That would be a matter of preference/opinion of the maintainer(s) of the said system as a whole.